# how to save gmail emails accordingly in database

Tags: php, mysql, gmail

i want to have a script that will save gmail emails from an account in mysql db  using php. Mails(both freshly new and reply ones) will be marked to be in the same category if they have the same subject. That is just the same way in gmail or yahoo mail.

So far as I know gmail IMAP does not give the facility to track which are the reply mails.

Which API or whatever should I use??

The script will keep running.

Do I need to use scheduled task for that?

Comment: Drop the gmail, gmail is just an email client. You will need to read IMAP emails through PHP periodicly.

Comment: I wonder why such a question is being downvoted?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't worked with that, but as i Google around, it turns out GMAIL provides [IMAP Extensions API](http://code.google.com/intl/lv/apis/gmail/imap/). And there you have an option to [Access to the Gmail thread ID: X-GM-THRID](http://code.google.com/intl/lv/apis/gmail/imap/#x-gm-thrid)

Answer (score 0):

The reply emails as you call them are stored in the sent-mail folder, so just download them with IMAP.

You can track how emails go together using the `In-Reply-To:` and `References:` headers. Using the subject is not reliable.

Comment: what is the unique identifier of a  mail .. how r the reply mails tracked? 'So far as I know gmail IMAP does not give the facility to track which are the reply mails.' am i right?

Answer (score 0):

@sof_user : every mail will have message_id in the header. google tracing the email with the id, if it is reply, then IN-REPLAY-TO will have the same id.